# Take only the second element that has the same name in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm **scraping** a website for college work, and I am having trouble getting only the second text in a span.I have seen that you can use below to get the text:

`gross = container.find_all('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})`
`print(gross)`

I have as a result this:

`[<span data-value="845875" name="nv">845.875</span>, <span data-value="335.451.311" name="nv">$335.45M</span>]`

how do I get only the values contained with in the second `data-value`, in a way that can replicate for others span's ?

Comment: ``gross[1].text`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```py
gross = container.find_all('span', attrs = {'name':'nv', 'data-value':'335.451.311'}) 
print(gross)
```

If this data val keeps changing then you don't have any other choice but to use gross[1].